me/accounts not returning all pages owned by a facebook user
There are several that are similar, none of them relate to this specific problem. I am trying to get FB pages owned by a user. Before this i was getting issue that business pages were not listing so i found that i need to add business_management permission and the permission fixed the issue. But now i am still not getting some user's (previously connected and also sometimes new users) pages and not able to connect with my app. What can be the reason as i have also tried remove app from business integration setting.
But... when I visit the page on the web, I am an admin. I have full access to all the admin functions. It also appears in my list of pages in the Pages Manager app on Android.
I have read the documentation for the hint as to what I am doing wrong, and nothing found helpful.
i have tried it with another app (similar to my requirement) and the page is listing. I'm not able to find what i am missing in my request (may be any permission).

Try and remove the permission from the user's app settings, and then ask for it again.
